# Uploading Date columns into BigQuery with Python

Tags: python, dataframe, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to upload a dataframe into bigquery that contains date columns.
I'm using the code below:

```
base_tedesco_mae.loc[:, to_date] = base_tedesco_mae.loc[:, to_date].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce', format="%Y-%m-%d", utc=False))
```

When i check the data type in GBQ, i notice that my dates are 'TIMESTAMP' and not 'DATETIME' as i wanted. Does anybody know how to change this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I don't get a error, but my dates stay as TIMESTAMP type in GBQ, and i wanted a DATETIME type